# Sending SMS in Android,

Tags: android

I have already implemented sending message to multiple users.
Now here is what i want to do further

1. I have button on My main activity on button click Android's Default contact book should open
2. When i click on the particular contact from phonebook, then
   particular phone number   from that
   selected contact should occur in
   editbox in my main activity.

I have called intent on click event of button like this

```
addcontact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View V) {
        Intent ContactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(ContactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);             
    }
});
```

Now i m stuck in how to retrieve phone number from OnActivity results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work though I haven't tested it:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String number = "";
    Uri result = data.getData();

    // get the contact id from the Uri
    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
    Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
        switch (type) {
        case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
            // do something with the Home number here...
            break;
        case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
            // do something with the Mobile number here...
            break;
        case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
            // do something with the Work number here...
            break;
        }
    }
    phones.close();
}
```

You need to use onAcitivtyResult and a [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to get the numbers.
You may also want to check that the returned result is actually from your ContactPickerIntent and not a different activity via:

```
switch (requestCode) 
        case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
```

Comment: I have got the solution...
Thanks for the effort...
I would like to add that if we are using like this then it will work on version 2.0,2.2 But it will not work on 1.6..

Anyway thanks for your effort